# Short story takes place as a rescue mission on an unnamed (I believe) planet with Medusa as the only resident

Tags: story-identification, astronauts

I read this short story as part of a college class on mythology in the 80s. Not sure of the publication date of story, author, title, etc.

The gist of the story is a rescue mission has been sent to a planet (not sure which planet) in search of missing astronauts. The rescuer finds what appears to be statues of the missing.

Near the end of his exploration, he sees what appears to be a shadow behind him of a woman whose hair is blowing in the wind. Just as he turns, he remembers there's no wind.

I have searched all over Google using tags, possible lines, with/without quotation marks.

I would love it if anybody had a clue as to the title of this story or even a link to it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "[Forms Of Things Unknown](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BuMImjiywMgC&pg=PT135&lpg=PT135&dq=%22wanted%20to%20feel%20again,%20to%20be%20flesh,%20not%20stone%22&source=bl&ots=-B1wEd81JR&sig=-6Iak5lgpOtA4QgD_yjfQaki3To&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xzCdVOK2CsjyUtyYgLgL&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22wanted%20to%20feel%20again%2C%20to%20be%20flesh%2C%20not%20stone%22&f=false)" by CS Lewis.

I read this short story when I was a kid and it haunted me for years.

> He fixed the set so that he could stand with his back to the sun. He
>   worked the gimmicks. 'Jenkin, speaking from the Moon,' he began.
>
> His
>   own huge black shadow lay out before him. There is no noise on the
>   Moon. Up from behind the shoulders of his own shadow another shadow
>   pushed its way along the dazzling rock. It was that of a human head.
>   And what a head of hair. **It was all rising, writhing—swaying in the
>   wind perhaps. Wry thick the hairs looked. Then, as he turned in
>   terror, there flashed through his mind the thought, 'But there's no
>   wind. No air. It can't be blowing about.' His eyes met hers.**

Comment: Just saw the reply! Had been checking for a few months but gave up on a reply. I gave up too quickly!

Thank you! I thought this was a great story and it's been driving me crazy trying to find it!!

Obviously, it's stuck in my head as well and I couldn't stop thinking about it!

Thank you again!